# Using like with varchar2 that have null value at start

Tags: oracle, plsql

The following is excerpt from my procedure that creates logical backup after checking the `backup_schedule` value in `schema_info` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BACKUP_EXECUTE 
(
  [...]
) AS 
[...]
  schemas varchar2(255):=' ';

  cursor schema_name is select upper(schema_name) schema_name from schema_info
    where backup_schedule like '%'||to_char(sysdate, 'D')||'%'
    and exists (select * from dba_users where username=upper(schema_name));

  type sl is table of schema_name%ROWTYPE
    index by pls_integer;

  schema_list sl;
BEGIN
  open schema_name;

  fetch schema_name bulk collect into schema_list;

  close schema_name;
  if schema_list.count != 0 then

    for indx in 1..schema_list.count loop      
      if(schemas not like '%'||schema_list(indx).schema_name||'%') then
        if indx>1 then
          schemas:=schemas||',';
        else
          schemas:=null;
        end if;
        schemas:=schemas||''''||schema_list(indx).schema_name||'''';
      end if;
    end loop;

  [...]
  end if;

  EXCEPTION
  [...]
END;
```

Besides the fact, that this can be done better, I want to concentrate on one thing. As we know `like` is not working with `null` values. Should I leave the code as above and write some start value which later is deleted or is it better to use `nvl(schemas,' ')` in `if` statement?

Comment: I think you can get rid of most of the code by using `DISTINCT` and string aggregation, see http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php